# Dynamically generating tables from nested json in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to iterate over deeply nested json. My end goal is dynamically render the json data into tables.

I want to mention I am new to Angular. So it may a fundamental misunderstanding of what im using. If that is the case, being pointed in a general direction would be appreciated.

I am currently attempting to pass the json into the AppComponent from a renderJsonComponent, and recursively calling the renderJson component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { items } from './testData'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public renderedItems = items
}
```

```
<app-render-json [renderedItems]="renderedItems"></app-render-json>
```

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-render-json',
  templateUrl: './render-json.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./render-json.component.css']
})
export class RenderJsonComponent {
  @Input() public renderedItems;
}
```

```
<ul *ngIf="renderedItems.facilities">
   {{ renderedItems }}
  <li *ngFor="let items of renderedItems">
    <app-render-json [renderedItems]=items></app-render-json>
  </li>
</ul>
```

currently, it will render [object Object] and the error I am getting is:

```
RenderJsonComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3185)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22004)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23265)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23227)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23861)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23821)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RenderJsonComponent.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23813)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23209)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23450)
```

jsonData

```
const data = {
    "places": [
        {
            "thing": "city",
            "address": {
                "address": "abc 123, USA",
                "address1": "",
                "address2": "",
                "address3": "",
                "city": "",
                "stateProvince": "",
                "postal": "",
                "lat": 0,
                "lng": 0
            },
            "phoneNumber": "1800-pleasedontbemean",
            "aaaaa": [
                {
                    "bbbbbb": [
                        {
                            "code": "",
                            "description": "help"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hours": {
                        "normal": [
                            {
                                "type": "",
                                "hours": "24/7"
                            }
                        ],
                        "saturday": [
                            {
                                "type": "",
                                "hours": "23/8"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "notes": "none"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
 }
```

I would like dynamically render tables based on the json.

Comment: The "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays" clearly states what is wrong, so I would start by looking at what type "renderedItems" actually is, is it really an array. Suspect you are passing an object

Comment: Is that the start of your JSON? @than is right. your JSON is probably not in array format.

Comment: @Sarah, my apologies  - I changed the data to represent the structure I am working with.

Comment: @ncubed Have you tried something like <li *ngFor="let place of renderedItems.places">{{place.phoneNumber}}</li> to check if that prints anything first?

Comment: @Sarah - yes, i've tried that. I get [object Object] as the output.

Comment: @ncubed ok. but it looks like places is an array so that should work. can you try logging renderedItems.places to the console? console.log(renderedItems.places);

Comment: @Sarah - so that worked. But it just prints the value of phoneNumber, Id like to print all values in the structure.